# Xcode Instruments - Zombies - what am I looking for?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, nszombie, nszombieenabled

When I run Project/Profile in Xcode and choose "**Zombies**", the app runs in the simulator with "`NSZombie detection`" enabled. But what should I be looking for to tell me that there is a problem? All I see is the Allocation instrument running and the statistics below. Where will it actually show me that a `Zombie` was detected?

Comment: This explains it pretty thoroughly: [iPhone Memory Debugging with NSZombie and Instruments](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/) [Caveat: Demonstrated using XCode3 - all applicable to XCode4 though]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You will get the leak above the object allocation bar.
Check this image;
[image]

For a reference, check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQtPr8bkB3g)