# What is the correct way to create a custom setter for a weak property in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

If I declare a property like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) Foo *someProperty;
```

and I then declare a custom setter like so:

```
- (void)setSomeProperty:(Foo *)someProp {
    _someProperty = someProp;
    //...more custom stuff
}
```

is there anything wrong with this? That is, the compiler should automatically synthesize the _someProperty ivar with the __weak modifier, so just doing the assignment in the setter above should suffice, correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that's all there is to it.  Of course you can specify a custom iVar if you'd like something other than `_someProperty` like:

```
@synthesize someProperty = someProperty_;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! So, as I understand it, if you are writing a custom setter in ARC, the only time you need to worry about "overriding" the attributes on the property declaration is if you have the property declared with atomic (in which case you would need to @synchronize around setting the iVar) and copy (in which case your assignment statement would look like _someProperty = [someProp copy]; )