# How to define the setter method with weak attribute in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have to do some operation on setter method which have weak property attribute. But, I don't know how to do it. Could anybody help me on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to create a custom setter for a weak property in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607404/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-custom-setter-for-a-weak-property-in-objecti)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you declared a weak property in the header like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) Bar *foo;
```

you can simply implement the setter method like this:

```
- (void)setFoo:(Bar *)foo {
    _foo = foo;
    // do your custom things here
}
```

where `_foo` is the automatically generated instance variable for your property.

Comment: Have you tested this code for the case that automatic zeroing of the pointer is still working?