# Objective-C >> Is There a Way to Look at an Object Retain Count Table "on the Run"?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, retaincount

While using ARC, life is much easier in terms of memory management; but, let's say I wish to look at a certain object while the app is running and see how many pointers are pointing to it at each certain point in the code. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It's not recommended to relay on retain count in any way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262403/find-where-object-is-retained-with-arc hope this help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the retain count using `-retainCount` or `CFGetRetainCount` but it will almost never give you any meaningful or useful information. Objects can be added to autorelease pools, retained by the various internals of the objective-c runtime or Apple frameworks, ARC, etc. You shouldn't really care how many people have retained an object, only whether you need a strong reference to it at any point in time.

Relevant link: [whentouseretaincount.com](http://whentouseretaincount.com/)