# iOS non-zero reference count in ARC and cannot dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

[image: ARC view in instrument]

Hi All

I am trying to dealloc a ViewController in ARC mode.
However, the RefCount is always non-zero.

I have tried to set all object to nil and all subviews to removeFromSuperview + nil;
and timer to invalidate + nil;
still the counter = 2;

Is there a way to trace which pointer is still in retain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using blocks you might also create retain cycle there. E.g. a block is referenced by an object and inside this block you are referencing object or calling instance method for object.
Another option for retain count not dropping to 0 is that you have registered abject as observer for notification.

You might find this answer helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12286739/2261423

Example of strong reference cycle from apple docs:

```
self.block = ^{
        [self doSomething];    // capturing a strong reference to self
                               // creates a strong reference cycle
    };
```

Comment: Yes this is likely the issue, I have made a lot of block in between... is there any fast search to find out which block is retaining the controller?

Comment: It's the block you keep a reference to in you object. It's nicely shown in apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html section "Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing self"

self.block = ^{
        [self doSomething];    // capturing a strong reference to self
                               // creates a strong reference cycle
    };

Comment: Compiler would throw a warning, if there was a retain cycle with block.

Comment: Compiler would throw a warning if it can recognise the situation, but it can't always do that. And of course you need to turn warnings on!!!

Answer (score -1):

@Billy, why are you doing this? You may not worry about deallocation when using ARC. Controller will be deallocated automatically, when there will be no references *to* the controller. Yes, views do not refer to controller, they are referred by it! So removing that views will not affect **retain count** of the controller. If you really want to remove View Controller from memory, remove it from parent view controller and set all links to nill.

Comment: thanks for advice. Because the memory is kept high and I want to free the memory up, thus I try to put a breakpoint in dealloc and it is somehow not called. It means I have some "hidden" pointer referring to the controller. It is very difficult to find it all out...