# UINavigation Controller crash on showing ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` in which there is a MainViewController with `UITableView` and a ToolBar button. Selecting a `UITableViewCell` will push to `SecondViewController` and tapping Toolbar button will push to `ThirdViewController`, both with StoryBoard segue.
Both ViewControllers are pushed OK for the first time, but when `UINavigationController` pushes the `SecondViewController` first and pop back to `MainViewController`, then pushing `ThirdViewController` will cause the app to crash. So I thought something has to be wrong with `ThirdViewController's` code, but the error message is:

```
SecondViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x115621d0
```

The weird thing is why `SecondViewController` is in the error message while I'm pushing the `ThirdViewController`?
I put breakpoint and `prepareForSegue` on `MainViewController` is getting called without error, `viewDidLoad` on `ThirdViewController` is getting called after that without error, but when I click continue at the end of `viewDidLoad` the app crashes. 
Using Instruments with Zombies enabled shows this: 
[image: Instruments]

I'm pushing `ThirdViewController`, why the code goes into `SecontViewController` segue? I couldn't get any idea what is wrong with the code? I'm using ARC, so I didn't released anything by mistake.

Screenshot of SB:

Class definition of all three View Controllers

```
// MainViewController.h
@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, SecondViewControllerDelegate> {
    BOOL _thumbnailTapped;

}

- (void)showQuickTour:(id)sender;
- (void)Purchased;
- (IBAction) pickThumbnailImage:(id)sender;


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageTitles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageImages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageImages_3_5;


@property (nonatomic, weak)   IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *editOptionsLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache* thumbnailCache;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache* emailCountCache;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   NSIndexPath* currentIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL deleting;
@property (nonatomic, weak)   ABContact *returnedMailingList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SoundEffect* deleteFX;

@end


//SecondViewController.h
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)getBackCurrentMailingList:(id)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(ABContact *)currentMailingList;
@end


@protocol ModalViewDelegate
@optional
- (void) getBackGroup:(NSDictionary *) group;
- (void) getBackContacts:(NSArray *)c andEmails:(NSArray *)e;
- (void) getBackPastedContacts:(NSArray *)contacts;
- (void) getBackPullView:(BOOL)pullled;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController <ModalViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
    ABContact *currentML;
    BOOL _isViewPulled;
}

- (IBAction) pickImage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) composeEmail:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) PasteGroup:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) dismissPopUp:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, weak)     IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *composeButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSCache*                thumbnailCache;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   ABContact*              currentML;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSMutableDictionary*    currentMailingList;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSArray*                pastedContatcs;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSDictionary*           groupDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) ABRecordID             currentRecordID;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   UIView*                 fadingView;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   UILabel*                fadingLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   UIActivityIndicatorView* fadingActivityIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, weak)     id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   SoundEffect* deleteFX;

@end


//ThirdViewController.h
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *request;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *product;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productID;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *versionLabel;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *productLabel;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *productDescription;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *purchaseButton;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *soundFXSwitch;
@property (weak,   nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingIndicator;

- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)restorePurchase:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)switchSoundFX:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showQuickTour:(id)sender;

-(void)getProductID:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end
```

Comment: Can you show an image of your SB?

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of code. Just copy and paste the code directly and use the `[]` button to format it.

Comment: could you post code for the class declarations as well?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 if you meant StoryBoard it's added.

Comment: @simply_me I've pasted definition code of all three view controllers

Comment: the declaration seem fine. just out of curiousity have you used "respondsToSelector" anywhere in the code?

Comment: @simply_me No, but I've used `NSNotificatioinCenter addObserver: selector: name: object:` 3 times in the code of MainViewController for Entering foreground, showing quick tour at the first launch and showing App Store rating at 5th launch.

Comment: are you assigning secondVC as UINavigationControllerDelegate? if yes, try setting that value to nil in dealloc

Comment: you can also try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11171042/2365064

Comment: @simply_me Set `self.navigationController.delegate` to `nil` in `viewWillDisappear:` method when SecondViewController is Popped (not pushed) to its parent View Controller (MainViewController). Solved the problem. Thanks Man, you've saved my life! :)

Comment: I had set `delegate` value to nil in `dealloc` method before asking this question, But the point was when `dealloc` method is called, the `SecondViewController` has been removed from the hierarchy and setting `delegate` to `nil` was not going to solve the problem. But adding the code to `viewWillDisappear:` solved it!

Comment: @simply_me There is no answer in this thread! only comments! I up voted both of your comments. If you write an answer I'll mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check if you assigning secondVC as UINavigationControllerDelegate? if yes, try setting that value to nil in viewWillDisappear

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Modified the answer :).