# Issue found in Xcode 5.1.1 and not in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have a problem if i build my application from Xcode 5 and 
run the same on a device with iOS 8 i see a crash with a error message

```
[myViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView:] message sent to deallocated instance 0x1846c960
```

I have allocated the class as below

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyViewController *myViewController;

myViewController =[[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
myViewController.userDetailsDict=userDetailsDict;
[self.navController pushViewController:self.myViewController animated:FALSE];
```

if i build the same application from Xcode 6, then i don't see any issue, it works fine.

Has any one faced an issue of similar kind. Any Help ?

Comment: Just a small remark, **don't** capitalize your property names. It does not fit in with the Objective-C style.

Comment: Include your property declaration for MyViewController, please.

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) MyViewController *myViewController;

Comment: is it happening after pop of your view controller or at time of push?

Comment: @abhishekkharwar At the time of push.

Answer (score 1):

That warning appears as a result of having [NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4) enabled in your build scheme (see linked question).

At some point, `[MyViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView:]` is being called when `MyViewController` no longer exists - there were no more references to the object so it was deallocated.

---

As for why this happens on Xcode 5 and not Xcode 6, this is likely a result of your app's configuration or state in the simulator compared to the device - for example, does one environment contain data or settings that the other does not?

From your code, I can see that `MyViewController` is probably a `UITableViewDataSource`. Does one device/simulator contain table view data that the other does not? If so, that is why the error would appear in one environment but not the other. It *would* appear in both, but only one has the necessary settings/configuration in order to trigger the method being called.

In order to resolve the problem, you need to monitor the object lifecycle of `MyViewController` - that is, when is it created, when is it accessed and when is it/might it be released. At some point your view controller is being released when you still want to use it. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170614/viewcontroller-respondstoselector-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-crash/11171042) provides an excellent guide on how to use Instruments to track down and fix these sorts of errors.