# Crash issue in viewForHeader in section method

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am getting this crash issue when dragging the Control centre while using my app. Crash message is `[ViewController tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17dbb9a0`

**Code is:**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == self.groupsArray.count)
    {            
        customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 24.0)];
        [customView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        return customView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I am using Xcode 6 and enabled ARC . Could any one please help me to resolve this issue.

I have tried to take the help of Properties but doesn't work. Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: Which line does this error occur on? Have you used an exception breakpoint?

Comment: The problem is your ViewController instance. That's the object that gets deallocated. That this method is involved is just a symptom. You should show how you create and present that ViewController

Comment: Hey @ZeMoon I have used breakpoint but doesn't show the error in the viewForHeaderInSection method

Comment: hey @MatthiasBauch I think the issue is not with the view controller . If I comment the viewForHeaderInSection method I am not getting any crashes.

Comment: Are you explicitly calling the method someplace in your code?

Comment: No I am not calling externally anywhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11171042/1059705 To track the deallocated instance

Comment: @Bala I know which method is causing for the crash issue but couldn't solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

delegate of your tableview is deallocated whenever viewForHeaderInSection is called.
 make sure your viewcontroller is the delegate and check when and where it is getting deallocated.