# Getting error in async calls if the View Controller is no longer exists

Tags: ios, asynchronous, exc-bad-access

I have a remote service that i call and it processes the request asynchronously. When the data is returned, i'll refresh my local UI.

But sometimes when the View disappears and if asynchronous call is still in the queue then the app crashes with error `EXEC BAD ACCESS` (i.e. the object is already released) i.e.

> My app crashes when the service returns but the ViewController is disposed.

Mainly i am getting error when calling `[delegate respondsToSelector:@selector (methodName:)]`, after the the view controller is no longer exist.

May be i need to cancel all my asynchronous calls (running or waiting in queue) in `viewWillDisappear`. But i am not able to cancel the running calls.

I have already tried [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/18138513/2945616) but in `viewWillDisappear` my `self.navigationController.delegate` is already nil.

**Edit:**

**Method to call service:**

```
{
    NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“%@method_name”,Base_URL]]];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setTimeOutSeconds:600];
        [request setPostValue:userID forKey:@“id”];

        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

        [request startAsynchronous];

    }];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

And my `requestFinished` method (where my app crashes)

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // some stuff
    // It's working fine when I normally run my app but fails when I rapidly changes the View Controller.
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(gotResponseData:)]) // Here my app crashes
   {
       [delegate gotResponseData:responseDict];
    }
}
```

**Delegate property in .h file:**

`@property (nonatomic,assign)id <protocolName>delegate;`

Mainly this app crashes when I quickly switches between View Controller.

I'll edit my question if needed.

Kindly provide me some guidance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of the async calls that is running? Are you using strong `self` references?

Comment: Why can't you cancel?

Comment: @Wain: I can cancel those running calls but when I execute  `[operationQueue cancelAllOperations]` it only cancel the calls which are in queue but not running calls.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh: Do I need to provide my code or the scenario when the app crashes?

Comment: Provide the code for how you're running these operations, how the result is passed back and the lines where the crash occurs.

Comment: @Wain: I have edited my question, included some coding stuff.
If any more edits needed, then let me know.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh: Edited my question. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your block operation you should use a weak reference to self so that if/when self is released the operation doesn't call an invalid reference.

Indeed, you shouldn't actually need the operation as you are starting an asynchronous process inside the operation anyway.

Your delegate property in self should also be weak as your code indicates the problem is that the delegate is using an unsafe unretained approach (because of where you say the crash occurs).

Generally you would only have one request running from self so you should maintain a reference to the request and cancel it if self is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Currently my delegate property is `(nonatomic,assign)`. If I changed it to `(nonatomic,assign,weak)`, then it is showing an error as “ `assign` and `weak` are mutually exclusive. So now do I need to change it to `(nonatomic,weak)` ??

And also can you please help me to make my `self` to `weak`.
I am actually very new to IOS.

Comment: You need to read the ARC documentation. Which will explain _why_ assign and weak are mutually exclusive, and that makes the problem obvious.

Comment: Actually i read [here](http://www.rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties#other-attributes) that assign is not preferred in modern Applications that’s why I do not read that in detail.
Now i read the ARC documentation in detail.
And now i know the reason. Thanks.