# On AlertView App Crash in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In iOS7. I am showing a `UIAlertView` and then we get notification which also show `UIAlertView`.On clicking `UIAlertView` my app is creash in iOS7.

it print log

```
-[AddNotification respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14b53e00
```

Comment: display your sum code

Comment: can you share your code and the error stack trace?

Comment: may be u have setted delegate to YES & not not implemented delegate method of alertview.

Comment: do yo need any action on button click of alertView?

Comment: then set delegate:nil when initializing alertView. Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

It means your memory is deallocated , if you are used any delegate method on that particular VC remove the delegate option so do this

```
 - (void)dealloc
{

for example if you are used any tableview or else ...

//if you have any table views these would also need to be set to nil
self.tableView.delegate = nil;
self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
}
```

**Option 2**

enable the `Instruments` please ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170614/viewcontroller-respondstoselector-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-crash)