# Crashing application with message ViewController respondsToSelector: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Trying to open a pdf in readerview with below code

```
self.appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
                self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.appDelegate.aNavController presentViewController:downloadView animated:NO completion:nil];
                });
```

It's working fine on iPhone but not working on iPad, showing:

> ViewController respondsToSelector: message sent to deallocated
>   instance.

After enabling zombie from scheme getting this kind of error

```
0x655d799 <+777>:  jmp    0x655d89e                 ; <+1038>
    0x655d79e <+782>:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
    0x655d7a1 <+785>:  calll  0x668711c                 ; symbol stub for: class_getSuperclass
    0x655d7a6 <+790>:  movl   %eax, %edi
    0x655d7a8 <+792>:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
    0x655d7ab <+795>:  calll  0x668721e                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
    0x655d7b0 <+800>:  movl   %eax, %esi
    0x655d7b2 <+802>:  testl  %edi, %edi
    0x655d7b4 <+804>:  jne    0x655d7d7                 ; <+839>
    0x655d7b6 <+806>:  movl   %ebx, %edi
    0x655d7b8 <+808>:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
    0x655d7bb <+811>:  calll  0x668721e                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
    0x655d7c0 <+816>:  movl   %eax, 0x10(%esp)
    0x655d7c4 <+820>:  movl   %esi, 0xc(%esp)
    0x655d7c8 <+824>:  movl   %edi, 0x8(%esp)
    0x655d7cc <+828>:  movl   -0x14(%ebp), %eax
    0x655d7cf <+831>:  leal   0x3028fa(%eax), %eax
    0x655d7d5 <+837>:  jmp    0x655d7ea                 ; <+858>
    0x655d7d7 <+839>:  movl   %esi, 0xc(%esp)
    0x655d7db <+843>:  movl   %ebx, %edi
    0x655d7dd <+845>:  movl   %edi, 0x8(%esp)
    0x655d7e1 <+849>:  movl   -0x14(%ebp), %eax
    0x655d7e4 <+852>:  leal   0x30290a(%eax), %eax
    0x655d7ea <+858>:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
    0x655d7ee <+862>:  movl   $0x4, (%esp)
    0x655d7f5 <+869>:  calll  0x65a94a0                 ; CFLog
    0x655d7fa <+874>:  movl   %edi, %ebx
    0x655d7fc <+876>:  movl   -0x10(%ebp), %esi
    0x655d7ff <+879>:  movl   %esi, (%esp)
    0x655d802 <+882>:  calll  0x668723c                 ; symbol stub for: sel_getName
    0x655d807 <+887>:  movl   %eax, %edi
    0x655d809 <+889>:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
    0x655d80c <+892>:  calll  0x6687242                 ; symbol stub for: sel_getUid
    0x655d811 <+897>:  cmpl   %esi, %eax
    0x655d813 <+899>:  je     0x655d83d                 ; <+941>
    0x655d815 <+901>:  movl   %eax, 0x10(%esp)
    0x655d819 <+905>:  movl   %edi, 0xc(%esp)
    0x655d81d <+909>:  movl   -0x10(%ebp), %eax
    0x655d820 <+912>:  movl   %eax, 0x8(%esp)
    0x655d824 <+916>:  movl   -0x14(%ebp), %eax
    0x655d827 <+919>:  leal   0x30291a(%eax), %eax
    0x655d82d <+925>:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
    0x655d831 <+929>:  movl   $0x4, (%esp)
    0x655d838 <+936>:  calll  0x65a94a0                 ; CFLog
    0x655d83d <+941>:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
    0x655d840 <+944>:  calll  0x6687218                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClass
    0x655d845 <+949>:  movl   -0x14(%ebp), %ecx
    0x655d848 <+952>:  movl   0x2eb65e(%ecx), %esi
    0x655d84e <+958>:  movl   %esi, 0x4(%esp)
    0x655d852 <+962>:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
    0x655d855 <+965>:  calll  0x6687128                 ; symbol stub for: class_respondsToSelector
    0x655d85a <+970>:  testb  %al, %al
    0x655d85c <+972>:  jne    0x655d88a                 ; <+1018>
    0x655d85e <+974>:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
    0x655d861 <+977>:  calll  0x668721e                 ; symbol stub for: object_getClassName
    0x655d866 <+982>:  movl   %eax, 0xc(%esp)
    0x655d86a <+986>:  movl   %ebx, 0x8(%esp)
    0x655d86e <+990>:  movl   -0x14(%ebp), %eax
    0x655d871 <+993>:  leal   0x30292a(%eax), %eax
    0x655d877 <+999>:  movl   %eax, 0x4(%esp)
    0x655d87b <+1003>: movl   $0x4, (%esp)
    0x655d882 <+1010>: calll  0x65a94a0                 ; CFLog
    0x655d887 <+1015>: int3   
    0x655d888 <+1016>: jmp    0x655d89e                 ; <+1038>
    0x655d88a <+1018>: movl   -0x10(%ebp), %eax
    0x655d88d <+1021>: movl   %eax, 0x8(%esp)
    0x655d891 <+1025>: movl   %esi, 0x4(%esp)
    0x655d895 <+1029>: movl   %ebx, (%esp)
    0x655d898 <+1032>: calll  0x66871b2                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
    0x655d89d <+1037>: int3   
    0x655d89e <+1038>: calll  0x6687680                 ; symbol stub for: getpid
    0x655d8a3 <+1043>: movl   %eax, (%esp)
    0x655d8a6 <+1046>: movl   $0x9, 0x4(%esp)
    0x655d8ae <+1054>: calll  0x66876da                 ; symbol stub for: kill
    0x655d8b3 <+1059>: nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)
```

Using instrumentation getting this kind of thing. can anyone help me figure out where is the exact issue

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XozXs.png)

Comment: your code is getting called right after your object is released from memory

Comment: u r right , but unable to detect where the exact issue

Comment: Is `aNavController ` weak?

Comment: i think this you are calling this block of ocode  in background is it true?

Comment: No, it's strong . @property (nonatomic,strong) UINavigationController *aNavController;

Comment: No, calling in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }

Comment: you should check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170614/viewcontroller-respondstoselector-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-crash

Comment: When it crashes? after presenting viewcontroller or before?

Comment: what is self.appDelegate possibly appDelegate object is deallocated

Comment: **Abu Ul Hassan**'s link in comment may be help.

Comment: respondsToSelector indicates a protocol call somewhere and the owner is being deallocated before it is being called.

Comment: Please check the image and let me help to figure out the issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XozXs.png

Comment: Are you using any UIWebView in your code ? If yes can you please post the relevant code ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I have a custom cell which contain UIWebview. Removing that stop crashing . Why this is so , any clue?

Comment: UIWebView *jocalWebViewObj = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.frame.size.width-10, cell.frame.size.height-10)];
        [cell addSubview:jocalWebViewObj];
        NSString *strHTMLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: %@; font-size: %i; color: #425563\">%@</span>",font.fontName,(int) font.pointSize,self.aexhbitor.exDetails];
        [jocalWebViewObj loadHTMLString:strHTMLString baseURL:nil];

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [self.exhibitorDetailTbleVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i]];
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[SpeakerDescriptionTableCell class]]) {
            
            SpeakerDescriptionTableCell *cellTable = [self.exhibitorDetailTbleVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i]];
            
            [cellTable.descriptionWebView setDelegate:nil];
            cellTable.descriptionWebView = nil;
            [cellTable.descriptionWebView stopLoading];
            
        }  .... also not working

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved the issue, hope this solution help others.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     SpeakerDescriptionTableCell *cell =(SpeakerDescriptionTableCell *)localObjCell;
     [cell.descriptionWebView stopLoading];
     [cell.descriptionWebView setDelegate:nil];
     cell.descriptionWebView = nil;
}
```